# How to draw an object 3D with a Vector3’s array in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I would like to know how I can draw a three-dimensional polygon from an array of Vector3.
My idea was to use the Shape() function and then the ExtrudeGeometry() function, but Shape() does not accept vector3 but only vector2.
Is there any way to create a line that connects all these points, then fill the area of the drawn perimeter, and then do the extrusion?